# at_end_of_stream on stdin in Prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I ask SICStus Prolog `?- at_end_of_stream.` on the top-level and immediately I get: `no`.

GNU Prolog and Scryer Prolog do the same.

Traella Prolog and SWI-Prolog, however, choose to wait for input before answering, and rumor has it that behaving like this has been quite common among Prolog systems—especially in the past.

If I look at the ISO-Prolog standard, that behavior becomes spurious:

> **8.11.8.5  Bootstrapped built-in predicates**
> The built-in predicates `at_end_of_stream/0` and `at_the_of_stream/1` examine the single stream-property `end_of_stream/1`.
>
> A goal `at_end_of_stream` is true iff the current input has a stream position end-of-stream or past-end-of-stream (7.10.2.9, 7.10.2.13).
>
> A goal `at_end_of_stream(S_or_a)` is true iff the stream associated with stream or alias `S_or_a` has a stream position end-of-stream.
>
> ```
> at_end_of_stream :-
>   current_input(S),
>   stream_property(S, end_of_stream(E)),
>   !,
>   (E = at ; E = past).
> ```
>
> [The the sake of brevity, I omitted the code for `at_end_of_stream/1`.]

So it appears that the standard is quite clearly on the side of SICStus Prolog and GNU Prolog.

So my question boils down to this:

> Is this "waiting" behavior simply non-conformance, a kind of anachronism justified on the basis of practicality / compatibility—or is there more to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Handling end of stream is hard, on the top-level it's even harder.

A very simple and basic top-level is like `sh` ([dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dash)). Prolog top-level is a bit similar, it differs by having auto-completion/choice (like Scryer Prolog, SWI-Prolog), not accepting input with **ctrl-D** but it could be like `sh`.

A query to test and better understand top-level is `?- get_char(C).%a` (where `C` binds to `%`, [source](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_testing#271)) and `?- get_char(C).` (when submitting with **enter**, `C` binds to `\n`, if submitting with **ctrl-D** then **waits** or binds `C` to `end_of_file`).

Why those query?
The top-level can be model as `read_term(user_input, Goal, []), call(Goal)`:

- Case `get_char(C).%a` submitted with **enter**: The query is parsed and the `user_input` is `%a\n` thus `C` binds to `%` and if `get_char(C)` is replaced by `at_end_of_stream` then `at_end_of_stream/0` fails.
- Case `get_char(C).` submitted with **enter**: The query is parsed and the `user_input` is `\n` thus `C` binds to `\n` and if `get_char(C)` is replaced by `at_end_of_stream` then `at_end_of_stream/0` fails.
- Case `get_char(C).` submitted with **ctrl-D**: The query is parsed and the `user_input` is empty. Now the stream position of `user_input` should be `end-of-stream` or `past-end-of-stream` if `read_term/3` is executed as procedurally specified in `8.14.1.1`:

  - If `user_input` doesn't have an end then with the note of `7.10.2.9` the stream postion can't be `end-of-stream` or `past-end-of-stream`. Is the stream reset and has `end_of_stream` property `not`? What happens if the stream doesn't have the property `eof_action(reset)`? In any case `get_char/1` **waits** and if `get_char(C)` is replaced by `at_end_of_stream` then `at_end_of_stream/0` fails (there is an opportunity for `at_end_of_stream/0` to wait here).
  - Else `user_input` has a size but it's unknown (or variable but still unknown) then:

    - If stream position is `end-of-stream` then `C` binds to `end_of_file` and if `get_char(C)` is replaced by `at_end_of_stream` then `at_end_of_stream/0` succeeds.
    - Else stream position is `past-end-of-stream` then `get_char/1` **waits** and if `get_char(C)` is replaced by `at_end_of_stream` then `at_end_of_stream/0` succeeds.

Sadly there is a bit of twisting at the end.

I might have missed/misread something if not then this undefinedness allows some optimization/simplification of the implementation, explains the difference between engine and also the actual top-level is more complicated that `read_term(user_input, Goal, []), call(Goal)` (even if it's the ideal one).

When it comes to `at_end_of_stream/0`, it doesn't seem like there is a reason to wait.

## Digression

If `at_end_of_stream/0` is implemented with `peek_char/1` without executing `eof_action` then that might explain the wait.

On other operating system, it may be different. I use and test on Linux.

On GNU Prolog (version 1.5.0), there is the [issue](https://github.com/didoudiaz/gprolog/issues/27) that a stream with property `eof_action(reset)` is never at end of stream. This explains why `at_end_of_stream/0` fails.

```
$ echo -n | gprolog --init-goal "(at_end_of_stream, write(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
not(end_of_file)
$ echo | gprolog --init-goal "(at_end_of_stream, writeq(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
not('\n')
```

`at_end_of_stream/0` fails even when the stdin is empty.

On Trealla Prolog (version v2.1.11):

```
$ echo -n | ./tpl -g "(at_end_of_stream, writeq(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
at
$ echo | ./tpl -g "(at_end_of_stream, writeq(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
not('\n')
$ echo -n | ./tpl -g "(stream_property(S, alias(user_input)), stream_property(S, end_of_stream(Eos)), at_end_of_stream(S), writeq(eos(Eos)), halt ; halt)"
eos(not)
```

The property `end_of_stream` doesn't agree with `at_end_of_stream/1` (permuting `stream_property/2` and `at_end_of_stream/1` doesn't change the result).

On Scryer Prolog (on master (6b8e6204957bfc3136ea39ec659d30627775260d) or rebis-dev (c1945caf11c0d202f4121de446f1694854dcba47)):

```
$ echo -n | ./target/release/scryer-prolog -g "(at_end_of_stream, write(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
not('\x0\')
$ echo | ./target/release/scryer-prolog -g "(at_end_of_stream, write(at), nl, halt ; peek_char(C), writeq(not(C)), nl, halt)"
not('\n')
```

`at_end_of_stream/0` fails even when the stdin is empty.

Comment: Anything happened since [#270](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_testing#270)?

Comment: With GNU Prolog version 1.5.0, `C = '%'` on #270 on the top-level.

Comment: No change. #270 does not test the top level loop which is out of scope, see 1 Scope, NOTE f. Thus, `?- read(X),X.` is used instead. And there everything is the same, even in 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

## How to make the `at_end_of_stream/0`/`stream_property/2` wait?

Using the top-level `read_term(user_input, Goal, []), call(Goal)`, the query `?- get_char(C), at_end_of_stream.` can wait.

The query `?- at_end_of_stream.` doesn't wait because of `read_term/3` since it needs to peek to determine the `end token` and it can update the stream position.

- If `user_input` doesn't have an end then with the note of `7.10.2.9`, `at_end_of_stream/0` fails.
- Else `user_input` has a size but it's unknown (or variable but still unknown) then `at_end_stream/0` **waits**. The query `get_char(C), at_end_of_stream.` is submitted with **enter**. The query is parsed and `user_input` is `\n`. Now `get_char/1` reads `\n`, `user_input` is empty and `get_char/1` should update stream position as specified by `8.12.1.1`. But `get_char/1` can't update `user_input` and needs not do an update by peeking, it can be left for when the user tries to observe with `at_end_of_stream/0`. Now `at_end_of_stream/0` **waits**.

Another way to make `at_end_of_stream/0` waits is to use the top-level `at_end_of_stream`. The initial stream position of `user_input` is unknown (the size of the stream is unknown) thus `at_end_of_stream/0` **waits**.

Small digression: `get_char/1` can't update the stream position of `user_input` unless it reads `end_of_file` in which case `user_input` stream position is updated to `past-end-of-stream`.

Comment: Note that peeking is a bit cumbersome since you have to use either `peek_char/1/2` or `peek_byte/1/2` depending on `text` or `binary`.

Comment: Removed the implementation detail. But that would be internally without `eof_action` being triggered.

Comment: Let's assume you are right when you say "it *can* wait". It clearly needs not wait, so what's the benefit in making it wait in these cases? (As a user I cannot rely on it. As an implementor choosing the "fail immediately" path is easier.)

Comment: Indeed using the note of `7.10.2.9`, it's much easier for the implementor but the user can't have an useful information. The wait is because there isn't any input to decide. So the stdin (`user_input`) is like a file, `at_end_of_stream/1` always gives the right result.

Comment: Yes, but if a user writing ISO-Prolog code cannot *depend* on `at_end_of_stream/1` behaving like this, what is it good for? Why not use `peek_char/1` / `peek_byte/1` as a portable alternative instead?

Comment: But `peek_char/1` can't replace `at_end_of_stream/1` due to `eof_action(reset)`. The wait of `at_end_of_stream/1` also "happens" for a file but the input comes from the hard drive while on stdin the input comes from the user. An example using pipe in [digression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543996/14414324) (Trealla in particular), there is no wait because of pipe. This mainly makes stdin behave like a file.